# How can I accept a windows x509 certificate automatically?

Tags: windows, testing, automated-tests, certificate, x509certificate

I am writing a test and windows seems to be prompting me for what certificate to use when using x509 client certificates.
I would like to have it automatically select one without user interaction (user interaction is bad when writing tests).
The problem is there seems to be no documentation on how this works in MSDN, could someone at least point me towards an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the server request a client certificate signed by a specific CA.

If only one certificate installed locally is issued by that CA then this should surpass the prompt.

Comment: I need more then one cert for the test.

Comment: Details please!

Comment: I guess I would need to know what you are trying to test and where from. Is it a webpage and if so which browser are you using? Is it IIS or Apache? Or something else entirely?

Comment: I have a process that requires me to use different certs for different parts of the use case, I need a browser agnostic approach... since certificate selection is a windows thing, not a browser thing... not sure why you are asking, but if you must know, I need all of them... all versions... hope that helps!